# Is Mac#doFinal() thread-safe in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, cryptography

In java, we need to generate HmacSHA1/256 message digests for too many text data, and of course parallel.

Now the question is, is `javax.crypto.Mac#doFinal(byte[]:arg)` thread-safe, or better the implementation SPI by sun/oracle(hotspot)?

All salt keys are the same, I'm thinking about having a prepared `Mac` obj and all threads call it for generating the message digest.

I could not understand and state it with [javadoc](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/crypto/Mac.java#Mac.doFinal%28%29).

If this guy is not thread-safe, is there any equivalent for this(maybe from Apache,...)?

thanks.

Comment: Given that a Mac is a stateful object, I doubt it can be used by multiple threads to generate several different digests. Why don't you create an instance each time you need to compute a Digest? Have you proven that caused a significant performance penalty, especially compared to the complex cryptographic computations involved in the digect itself? This sounds like premature optimization. At best, you could store Mac instances in a ThreadLocal to have one instance per thread.

Comment: @JBNizet we might need generate more than 10 digest at one second, I know about the process of generating a hash, and currently I generate one and keep for each thread. I just was wonder if I could have one global which all threads use this, I was thinking the `Mac` would copy the required info(data,key) with each request and generate it, so it would be thread-safe(and static method which is not). Hopefully it's kinda polled, and each thread has one. thanks

Answer (score 22):

None of the `javax.crypto.Mac#doFinal` methods are thread safe, as they change the internal state of the MAC.

This makes sense as the mac at any point, is something like the sum/xor of all previous MAC up to that point, so it **cannot be done** in parallel. And as far as I know, no MAC algorithm can work in parallel (as opposed to some encryption algorithms).

Having said the above, `Mac` is clonable, so if you have an instance primed with the salt, you can clone it and use the clones to calculate the MACs (I would test this though!)

Comment: In addition, it looks like the Mac object is not even "serially" thread-safe.

Comment: @StephenC That's because it isn't. HMAC instantiation should not be too heavy. Just generating a HMAC for each text is much preferred.

Comment: Augusto: you could create a hash function out of a hash tree (or Merkle tree). But the common hash algorithms are purely sequential yes.

Comment: I meant ... I've looked at the source code, and it looks like the Mac object and the underlying SPI object are not even serially thread safe.